# Rails Concurrency issue lockup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, puma

I have a rails app where an action never finishes and then times out.
Find the diagram below for better illustration.

1. My rails apps action is called
2. The action POSTs some data to another app
3. The other app needs something to complete the computation and calls a different action than the first of the Rails app
4. The other app gets a response and finishes the computation
5. The other app responds to the rails apps POST request
6. The view is rendered accordingly

[image: architecture]

**Now the issue**: The other app never gets a response from the main app. After the Rails apps request times out however, the response is sent (however too late of course) so I think it is somehow cued.

I don't understand how to fix that. I use rails 5 and Puma which should be able to handle parallel calls. Its also not a local issue, same happens in prod.

I use the recommended puma.rb config from Heroku

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

What do I do to fix this cueing?

Controller:

```
    # New method
    def live_preview_page
      preview_locale = params[:preview_locale]
      date = params[:date] # The date to preview
      page_id = params[:id]
      return if locale.nil? || locale =~ /not/ || date.nil?
      all_templates = Template.all.order('name ASC') # Maybe move to render_live_editor_page
      if date == "all"
        active_modules = @page.page_modules.order(rank: :asc)
      else
        active_modules = @page.page_modules.order(rank: :asc).to_a.valid_for(date: date.to_date)
        puts "Active modules: #{active_modules.count}"
      end
      active_modules_json = active_modules.each do |content_module|
        content_module.body = YAML.load(content_module.body).to_json
      end
      response = helpers.render_preview(active_modules, all_templates, preview_locale)
      renderer = ContentRenderer.new
      actionController = ActionController::Base.new
      rendered_helper = actionController.render_to_string(
        partial: '/pages/preview-helper-snippet', locals: {
        all_templates: all_templates, # For select when creating new modules
        modulesData: active_modules_json, # For rendering the JSON containing the data for the editor
        current_page: @page.id,
        localeLinks: renderer.generateStgPreviewURLs(SettingService.get_named_locales, @page.id),
        locale: preview_locale,
        all_locales: SettingService.locales_for_live_editor,
        all_sites_and_locales: SettingService.get_sites_and_locales
      })
      proxy_service = ProxyService.new
      proxy_service.get_page do |error, page_wrapper|
        # Note: Issue is that Vapor app generates warnings inline template : encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
        rendered_body_with_helper = response.body.force_encoding("UTF-8") + rendered_helper
        decorated_page = page_wrapper.gsub("__WIDGET__", rendered_body_with_helper)
        render inline: decorated_page
        return
      end

    end
```

Helper

```
  def render_preview(active_modules, all_templates, preview_locale)
    req = Request.new
    preview_body = {
      modules: active_modules,
      templates: all_templates,
      sites: SettingService.get_sites,
      configuration: {
        locale: preview_locale,
        site: "DE"
      }
    }
    req.send_request(
      url: "#{ENV["RENDER_SERVICE_URL"]}/preview",
      body: preview_body,
      options: {
        type: :post,
        json: true,
        username: ENV["RENDER_SERVICE_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME"],
        password: ENV["RENDER_SERVICE_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD"]
      }
    ) do |response_code, response|
      return response
    end
  end
```

Request is just a thin wrapper

```
  require "uri"
  require "net/http"

  class Request
    # Yields resonse_code (int), response
    # Parameters besides url: are optional
    def send_request(url:, body: {}, header: {}, options: {})
      uri = URI.parse(url)
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      if options.key? :type
        case options[:type]
        when :get
          request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, header)
        when :post
          request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
        end
      else
        # Default is GET
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, header)
      end
      if options.key?(:username) && options.key?(:password)
        request.basic_auth options[:username], options[:password]
      end
      unless body.class == String
        body = body.to_json.to_s
      end
      request.body = body unless body.empty?
      puts request.body
      # SSL is default
      if options.key? :ssl
        http.use_ssl = options[:ssl]
      else
        http.use_ssl = Rails.configuration.force_ssl
        #http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      end
      if options.key? :json
        request.add_field("Content-Type", "application/json")
      end
      response = http.request(request)
      yield response.code.to_i, response
    end
  end
```

Comment: The problem is not likely to be in Puma config. Can you paste the code of your controller/services responsible for handling the communication with the other app

Comment: @KartikeyTanna edited the question

Comment: I think this is my issue: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1433 but I don't know how to solve it :( How can I move to another worker or something?

Comment: Try increasing the number of workers. Set them to 5 or something. It might reduce the chances of error

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is (probably) not the answer you want - but it's the answer you need:

The best way to fix this is to avoid the loop in the request/response logic (where the rails app calls itself through the other app).

Concurrency might help delay the onset of the issue, but the issue will always occur as long as the loop exists.

For example, assume you have an 100 requests from clients to the Rails app.

Rails will call the other app and the other app's request will be queued as request number 101.

This can be solved with 100 threads (for example, 10 workers with 10 threads each)...

But what will your app do with 200 client requests?

This cycle is endless, the more clients you have the more concurrency you require before you experience DoS.

The only solution is to avoid the loop to begin with.

Either break it up to 3 apps or (better yet), avoid dependencies between micro services.